# Onclick doesn't work on mobile device to make a flip image

Tags: javascript, events, mobile

Onclick doesn't work on this code below. The idea is to flip an image by another.
How can I fix that ?
Thank's a lot

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("el-image").src = "https://labelhistoire.fr/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/texte-il-etait-une-fois-EL.png";
}

function myFunction2() {
  document.getElementById("el-image").src = "https://labelhistoire.fr/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/texte-il-etait-une-fois-FR.png";
}
```

```html
<html>
    
    <img id="el-image" style="margin-bottom:15px" src="https://labelhistoire.fr/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/texte-il-etait-une-fois-FR.png" />


<div class="grve-element grve-box-icon grve-large grve-side-icon grve-vertical-align-middle grve-layout-1" onclick="myFunction()" touchmove="myFunction2()" style="cursor: pointer"><div class="grve-box-title-wrapper"><div class="grve-wrapper-icon" style=""><i aria-hidden="true" class="grve-box-icon grve-text-primary-2 iconbreztel icon-breztelpicto-bretzel-noir"></i></div><div class="grve-box-title grve-leader-text">Uf Elsassich !</div></div></div>


</html>
```

Comment: It looks like it works fine, I just edit your question with the code-snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Your DOM structure is incorrect (missing `body` tag), which usually doesn't matter on modern browsers but can make a difference on certain mobile browsers.

I have added the `body` element and formatted it here:

```
<html>
<body>
  <img id="el-image" style="margin-bottom:15px"
    src="https://labelhistoire.fr/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/texte-il-etait-une-fois-FR.png" />

  <div class="grve-element grve-box-icon grve-large grve-side-icon grve-vertical-align-middle grve-layout-1"
    onclick="swapImage()"" style="cursor: pointer">
    <div class="grve-box-title-wrapper">
      <div class="grve-wrapper-icon" style=""><i aria-hidden="true"
          class="grve-box-icon grve-text-primary-2 iconbreztel icon-breztelpicto-bretzel-noir"></i></div>
      <div class="grve-box-title grve-leader-text">Uf Elsassich !</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Regarding the script, the function names are very similar and don't describe the purpose of the functions, so I have replaced them with one script with more explanatory naming.

```
const isSwapped = false;
const ELIMAGE = "https://labelhistoire.fr/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/texte-il-etait-une-fois-EL.png";
const FRIMAGE = "https://labelhistoire.fr/wp-content/uploads/2022/10/texte-il-etait-une-fois-FR.png";

function swapImage() {
  if(isSwapped) {
    document.getElementById("el-image").src = ELIMAGE;
    isSwapped = false;
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("el-image").src = FRIMAGE;
    isSwapped = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I jsut added the `body` but that change nothing to my issue

Comment: Updated the answer with some more changes, could you try that out?